# renaming or creating the stored proc will cause server hang up

Tags: sql-server

I have an already existing stored procedure. But when I am trying to create the stored procedure with a new name it hangs up the server. But If I execute the same with its usuall name it works fine. Any idea whats going wrong. Why the newly created one is taking too much time

Script is fine. As with original one it works perfectly but As I copied the script to new it started hanging the server.

Comment: Can't tell you a thing, not without the script to look at.

Comment: I'm not a Sql server expert, but I think people here would require more information, like whether it happens for all SPs or only for a particular sp.. what was its old name.. what are you trying to rename it as.. The code snippet etc. etc..

Comment: Sometimes when working on a low powered dev machine, Management Studio/Enterprise Manager can appear to hang. Are you doing the new SP through a script, or through the GUI?

Comment: What I am doing is right clicking on the existing stored procedure named as set_xml and then from options -> selecting Script stored procedure as -> create to -> new query window editor. and once its opened I change the name e.g set_xml to set_xml_test. When I execute this it hangs up. where as I did the same thing with get_xml to get_xml_test it works fine. is there any caching issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the stored procedure is lengthy or your server is heavily loaded, it might take a while to create. Give it a few minutes, just to be sure.

Perhaps a buggy or poorly performing DDL (Data Definition Language) trigger is defined on the database. It might be doing something different in the different cases you mention. You can find DDL triggers under Programmability, Database Triggers for the database.

You might try to see if this happens with all stored procedures that you try to clone in this way or only the particular stored procedure that you mention.

The last thing I can think of is that the system tables could be corrupt. Run a CHECKDB.